# InDesign Smart Reflow not working

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I'm trying to get InDesign to add new pages when I overset text *while typing*.

I have the preferences for Smart Reflow correct, but I'm not sure if my text frame is properly released; I still have the upper-left icon saying "this story is from the master's primary text flow" and if I change the frame in the master, my other frames do change.

I've tried to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the frame to release it, but it does nothing. It does work on other master-page items though. *Object > Anchored Object > Release* is also greyed out.

Not sure what's happening here.

Comment: Are your frame threaded within the master pages ? If not InDesign won't know where to report the overflowing text…

Answer (score 1):

You can check if every single pages on a master have threaded text frames or do this connection:
[image]

Once it's done, you can go onto the pages, override a frame and start adding text. Then as smart reflow is activated, new pages will be added if text temporarly overflows.

[image]